# Python/Pandas How to put comma after every number in a string

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

For example you have `"blablabla 23423451, neemememem 5688234 hhojvz 3451, yoea"`.

Output should look like this `"blablabla 2342345, neemememem 5688234, hhojvz 345, yoea"`

**If there is already a comma, just skip**.

Note: Such text in the dataframe, there are bunch of it. So, ideally would be in pandas. All numbers and text are unique (no dublicates). Length of digits in a number are random.

| text |
| --- |
| blablabla 2342345 neemememem 5688234 hhojvz 345 yoea |
| asdffgh 645655 neemememem 5688234 hhojvz 345 yoeablablabla 2342345 neemememem 5688234 hhojvz 345 yoeablablabla 2342345 ghhjfg 777777 hhojvz 345 ertert 698666666 neemememem 5688234 hhojvz 345 yoea |
| blablabla 2342345 neemememem 5688234 hhojvz 345 yoeablablabla 2342345 neemememem 5688234 hhojvz 345 yoeablablabla 2342345 neemememem 5688234 hhojvz 345 yoeablablabla 2342345 neemememem 5688234 hhojvz 345 yoeablablabla |
| 5688234 hhojvz 345 yoeablablabla 2342345 neemememem 5688234 hhojvz 345 yoeablablabla 2342345 neemememem 5688234 hhojvz 345 yoeablablabla 2342345 neemememem 5688234 hhojvz 345 yoea |
| blablabla 2342345 neemememem 5688234 hhojvz 345 yoea |
| sdf 2345 |

Comment: Is possible comma in original data after digit?

Comment: yep it could be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(r'(\d+)(?!,)\b', r'\1,', regex=True)
```

How it works

```
(\d+) # capture digits
(?!,) # not followed by comma
\b    # ensure word boundary
```

Replace with: captured group (`\1`) and comma

output:

```
text
0                                                                                                                                                                                blablabla 2342345, neemememem 5688234, hhojvz 345, yoea
1                        asdffgh 645655, neemememem 5688234, hhojvz 345, yoeablablabla 2342345, neemememem 5688234, hhojvz 345, yoeablablabla 2342345, ghhjfg 777777, hhojvz 345, ertert 698666666, neemememem 5688234, hhojvz 345, yoea
2  blablabla 2342345, neemememem 5688234, hhojvz 345, yoeablablabla 2342345, neemememem 5688234, hhojvz 345, yoeablablabla 2342345, neemememem 5688234, hhojvz 345, yoeablablabla 2342345, neemememem 5688234, hhojvz 345, yoeablablabla
3                                         5688234, hhojvz 345, yoeablablabla 2342345, neemememem 5688234, hhojvz 345, yoeablablabla 2342345, neemememem 5688234, hhojvz 345, yoeablablabla 2342345, neemememem 5688234, hhojvz 345, yoea
4                                                                                                                                                                                blablabla 2342345, neemememem 5688234, hhojvz 345, yoea
5                                                                                                                                                                                                                              sdf 2345,
```

Alternative regex: `(\d+)(?!,)(?!\d)`, this removes the condition on the word boundary and avoids to transform `'123,'` into `'12,3,'`